# Having a link within part of a message within a rails controller

Tags: ruby-on-rails, angularjs

I have an app in which the back end is rails, and the front end is built within angular.  I am in the process of editing my tokens controller that works on username and password errors.  In this controller is a method that creates all of the magic.

The problem that I am having is that within the fail messages, I am trying to create a link within the second half of my fail message.  Yet i've been having some problems with it.

```
  def create
   username = params[:username]
   password = params[:password]

   user = User.find_for_authentication(login: username)
   fail!(message: 'Account not found.  Please try again with new information or #{link_to(new_patient_registration_path)} click here to create a new account', status: :unauthorized) unless user
```

With what I have right now, I'm unable to have the message process. I wind up the entire error message being displayed, but the without the link.

Would anybody be able to take a quick gander at this for me to see what I am missing out on?

Much thanks in advance!

Comment: What exactly your problem is?

Comment: "Yet i've been having some problems with it." What exactly is the problem? As you currently have the code, what result is being produced?

Comment: With what I have listed below, i'm getting a complete error. I think possibly it could be because the angular side of the app within the routes.  I certainly would also be willing to go with just a outside link (like google or something) as well.

Comment: Be specific. What is the error message?

Comment: Ok, so with what I have right now, I wind up getting `Account not found. Please try again with new information or #{link_to(new_patient_registration_path)} click here to create a new account` completely listed out. Just the text, no links or anything have been rendered.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use [**view_context**](http://apidock.com/rails/AbstractController/Rendering/view_context)

```
fail!(message: "Account not found.  Please try again with new information or #{ view_context.link_to("Click here to create a new account", new_patient_registration_path)}".html_safe , status: :unauthorized) unless user
```